# How to get the value of each property in an object with nested objects and arrays?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way you could loop through an object with multiple nested levels of objects and arrays and extract only all the bottom level property values?

In this example I would want it to console.log:
"Live JSON generator",
3.1,
"2014-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
true
and further down:
"Jane Doe",
"888-555-1212",
"spouse"

```js
let test = {
  "product": "Live JSON generator",
  "version": 3.1,
  "releaseDate": "2014-06-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "demo": true,
  "person": {
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "phones": {
      "home": "800-123-4567",
      "mobile": "877-123-1234"
    },
    "email": [
      "jd@example.com",
      "jd@example.org"
    ],
    "dateOfBirth": "1980-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "registered": true,
    "emergencyContacts": [
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phone": "888-555-1212",
        "relationship": "spouse"
      },
      {
        "name": "Justin Doe",
        "phone": "877-123-1212",
        "relationship": "parent"
      }
    ]
  }
}

for(var key in test){
console.log(test[key]);
}

console.log(test);
```

Comment: You need to use recursion to repeat the process at each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) can be an easy way to check all values :

```js
var o = {"product":"Live JSON generator","version":3.1,"releaseDate":"2014-06-25T00:00:00.000Z","demo":true,"person":{"id":12345,"name":"John Doe","phones":{"home":"800-123-4567","mobile":"877-123-1234"},"email":["jd@example.com","jd@example.org"],"dateOfBirth":"1980-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","registered":true,"emergencyContacts":[{"name":"Jane Doe","phone":"888-555-1212","relationship":"spouse"},{"name":"Justin Doe","phone":"877-123-1212","relationship":"parent"}]}}

JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => typeof v == 'object' ? v : console.log(k, ':', v))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

Its not working because you are trying to read a JSON notated object wich is something different as an javascript object.

Try reading this [article](https://medium.com/@easyexpresssoft/object-literal-vs-json-7a2084872907#:%7E:text=The%20only%20noticeable%20difference%20is,data%20are%20valid%20Javascript%20object.) wich explains its properly.The tricky part is in the end.

And that, my son is where the answer lies!

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: There's nothing in the question about JSON.